# Output all members from a class defines as list

Tags: python, class, methods

Hi 
I've got a class that essentially is a list object holding a bunch of objects. I try to define a method to return all members, but it fails.
My code is:

```
class Stadion:
    def __init__(self,):
        self.__Tribuner=[]

    def setTribuner(self,tribuner):
        self.__Tribuner.append(tribuner)
    def getTribuner(self):
        pass
    def getAntallTribuner(self):
        antall=len(self.__Tribuner)
        return antall
    def addTribune(self,tribune):
        self.__Tribuner.append(tribune)
    def getTribuner(self):
        for tr in self.__Tribuner:
            return tr
```

Mye problem is  the getTribuner method.

/Andy.l

Comment: Don't use double underscores for attribute names unless you are sure you have to. :)

Comment: There are two getTribuner methods. You probably want neither and just access self.tribuner directly... this isn't Java.

Comment: You should select a correct answer. Yes, I know it's hard since most of the are correct in one way or another, but still. :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want

```
def getTribuner(self):
    return self.__Tribuner
```

or

```
def getTribuner(self):
    for tr in self.__Tribuner:
        yield tr
```

I would recommend to expose the standard [Python sequence interface](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) instead of your custom method names.  In your case it would be easiset to just derive `Stadion` from `list`.

Comment: When I try your first alternative i get the error:<__main__.SitteTribune object at 0x02BC2ED0>

Comment: That does not look like an error.  You get a `SitteTribune` object as return value -- don't know why.  The code in your post should always return a list.

Comment: That's not an error, it's an object. Apparently __Tribuner is not a list, but in your example above it is, so you have shown us slightly different code from what you are actually using.

Comment: SitteTribune is the class that the object in the list originates from.

Comment: So you actually did not get `<__main__.SitteTribune object at 0x02BC2ED0>`, you get `[<__main__.SitteTribune object at 0x02BC2ED0>]`, am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

The first time it hits `return tr`, it will quit.  You either want to return a generator (`yield tr`) or just `return self.__Tribuner`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def getTribuner(self):
    return self.__Tribuner
```

If don't want to return the list at once, you can use a [generator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators), like so:

```
def getTribuner(self):
    for tr in self.__Tribuner:
        yield tr

# usage it within a loop ...
for tr in instance.getTribuner():
    # process tr
```

This will return a list with all members in `self.__Tribuner`.

Sidenote: Concerning getters and setters in python, see this article:

- http://tomayko.com/writings/getters-setters-fuxors

Comment: This gives me the error <__main__.SitteTribune object at 0x02BC2ED0>

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to iterate through the items, swap `return` for `yield` in getTribuner.

Comment: It's not an error, it's an object, and that's in fact the object from the list, the one you wanted to return. So the code does exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass from `UserList.UserList`, and all this get's much easier. :) Or directly from list. Or even better do this:

```
class Stadion:
    def __init__(self,):
        self.tribuner=[]
```

Done. Thats all you need. You want to add a SitteTribun:

```
stadion = Stadion()
stadion.tribuner.append(SitteTribute())
```

Getting all the Tribuner:

```
stadion.tribuner
```

Looping over them:

```
for tribun in stadion.tribuner:
    whatevah()
```

Counting:

```
len(stadion.tribuner)
```

Yes. Python really is that easy. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Stadion(object):
    def __init__(self, tribuner):
        self.tribuner = tribuner
```

In your code, replace `stadion.GetTribuner()` with `stadion.tribuner`. Replace `stadion.SetTribuner(t)` with `stadion.tribuner = t`. To iterate over tribuner, use `for x in stadion.tribuner:` Now you're programming in Python rather than in Java.